# AdaptiveCards HostConfig Integration

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, botframework, web-chat

Does anyone know how to integrate a HostConfig for styling AdaptiveCards using webchat CDN in Asp.Net Core?

For example what is the file name?
Where does it go etc?

My project setup is:
Asp.Net Core with Angular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RenderWebChat takes a parameter called adaptiveCardHostConfig where you can pass your config. You can take a look at the webchat API reference here https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#web-chat-api-reference

Example

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        adaptiveCardHostConfig: {
            actions: {
                actionsOrientation: 'horizontal',
            }
        },
        styleOptions: {
            rootHeight: 500,
            rootWidth: 500,

        },
        directLine: dl,
        userID: '@Model.UserId',
        username: 'User',
        locale: 'en-US',
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```