# Adaptive card rendering in bot framework SDK v4 using visual c#

Tags: botframework, rendering, chatbot, adaptive-cards, adaptive-design

Hi I have developed a chatbot using core bot template in bot framework SDK v4 and I have published it in my azure portal, and Im able to open it in webchat. I am trying to add styles to my adaptive card and I have checked [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/net-html/render-a-card) , but I am not able to figure out how to render my card and set up the hostconfig.json to it.

this is my bot.cs file

```
  '''


  using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
  using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
  using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
  using Newtonsoft.Json;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Threading;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace asign.Bots
  {
   public class DialogAndWelcomeBot<T> : DialogBot<T>
     where T : Dialog
  {
      public DialogAndWelcomeBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState 
    userState, T dialog, ILogger<DialogBot<T>> logger)
         : base(conversationState, userState, dialog, logger)
     {
     }

     protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> 
   membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, 
  CancellationToken 
cancellationToken)
    {
        foreach (var member in membersAdded)
        {
            // Greet anyone that was not the target (recipient) of this message.
            // To learn more about Adaptive Cards, see https://aka.ms/msbot- 
   adaptivecards for more details.
            if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
            {
                var welcomeCard = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();
                var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(welcomeCard, ssml: "Welcome 
   to Bot Framework!");
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
                await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, 
   ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"), cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }

    // Load attachment from embedded resource.
    private Attachment CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment()
    {
        var cardResourcePath = 
   GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().First(name => 
   name.EndsWith("welcomeCard.json"));

        using (var stream = 
  GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(cardResourcePath))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var adaptiveCard = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return new Attachment()
                {
                    ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                    Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(adaptiveCard),
                };
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }

   '''

Please help me understand how to add a rendering method to above code and setup hostconfig. I would really appriciate the solution.
```

Comment: Hey, I think there's a slight missunderstanding here. The hostconfig and styling is not part of the bot framework but of the host thats rendering the card ie MS Teams or WebChat. Where do you want to apply styles?

Comment: Hi @TimCadenbach , I want to apply in webchat.

Comment: have a look here for example > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59382809/adaptivecards-hostconfig-integration

BotFramework does not render cards, you there is no host config in the bot framework. BotFramework only talks to hosts rendering cards.